# Mongoose complex query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Using mongoose. The Schema looks similar to this:

```
{
  "name" : String,
  "start" : Date, 
  "stop" : Date
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is to build a query, that ("AND"):

1. "name" == value
2. "start" - not exists OR "start" gte value
3. "stop" - not exists OR "stop" lte value

---

On the other hand, start and stop can be passed, or can be not passed (any of them).

All my attempts for while finished with some kind of Mongo Error :) So asking for some help.

Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [`AND`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) query logic can be expressed in either of the two ways :

**Implicit AND operation**:

```
Model.find({
    "name": name,
    "start": { 
        "$or": [
            { "$exists": false },
            { "$gte": start } 
        ]
    },
    "stop": { 
        "$or": [
            { "$exists": false },
            { "$gte": stop } 
        ]
    }
}).exec(callback);
```

**Explicit AND operation:**

```
Model.find({
    "$and": [
        { "name": name },
        {
            "start": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$exists": false },
                    { "$gte": start } 
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "stop": { 
                "$or": [
                    { "$exists": false },
                    { "$gte": stop } 
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.